# Sylius: Adding custom form type issue

Tags: symfony, sylius

On Sylius, I want to add 1 table for customer so that for specific customer type (e.g. VIP), extra fields has to be filled in. (One to One relationship)

Entity `CustomerExtra` created. Form type `CustomerExtraType` created.
Originally, I created the form type extends AbstractType. The customer form shows those extra fields but would not save the record.

Then I've found out Sylius should extends AbstractResourceType instead so I made the changes but error throw:

`Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Form\Type\CustomerExtraType": argument "$dataClass" of method "Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Form\Type\AbstractResourceType::__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.`

Here are the code:

service.yml

`services:
    app.form.type.customerextra:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\CustomerExtraType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type}`

config.yml

`sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.customerextra:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\CustomerExtra
                form: AppBundle\Form\Type\CustomerExtraType`

Customer Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use AppBundle\Entity\CustomerExtra as BaseCustomerExtra;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Customer as BaseCustomer;

class Customer extends BaseCustomer
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerExtra|null
     */
    protected $customerextra;

    public function __construct(BaseCustomerExtra $customerextra)
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->customerextra = $customerextra;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getCustomerExtra(): ?BaseCustomerExtra
    {
        return $this->customerextra;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setCustomerExtra(BaseCustomerExtra $customerextra): void
    {
        $this->customerextra = $customerextra;
        $this->customerextra->setCustomer($this);
        $customerextra->setCustomer($this);
    }
```

CustomerExtra Entity

```
private $customer;
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getCustomer(): ?Customer
{
    return $this->customer;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setCustomer(?Customer $customer): void
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
}
```

CustomerProfileType

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event): void {
    $customer = $event->getData();

    $event->getForm()->add('customerextra', CustomerExtraType::class, [
    ]);
});
```

CustomerExtraType

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;
use AppBundle\Entity\CustomerExtra;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Form\Type\AbstractResourceType;

class CustomerExtraType extends AbstractResourceType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('customer_extra1', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'sylius.form.customer.customer_extra1',
            ])
            ->add('customer_extra2', NumberType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'sylius.form.customer.customer_extra2',
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_customerextra';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'admin_customerextra';
    }

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the service definition:

```
services:
    app.form.type.customerextra:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\CustomerExtraType
        arguments:
            $dataClass: AppBundle\Entity\CustomerExtra
        tags:
            - { name: form.type}
```

Update: ok, try instead:

```
app.form.type.customerextra:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\CustomerExtraType
        arguments:
            - AppBundle\Entity\CustomerExtra
            - "Default"
        tags:
            - { name: form.type}
```

Comment: Error throw:
`Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Form\Type\CustomerExtraType": argument "$dataClass" of method "Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Form\Type\AbstractResourceType::__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while migrating from Sylius 1.0-beta to 1.3. I had the same error message about the same parent type:

> `Cannot autowire service "App\SomeBundle\MyType": argument "$dataClass" of method "Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Form\Type\AbstractResourceType::__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.`

What fixed it for me was disabling autowiring by default:

```
services:
    # Default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # Automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: false
```